# JQuery Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been using JQuery recently and all was going well…and then this came up and I'm very confused by it. I created a new page for testing purposes, and am getting the same error no matter what I try…

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="a" ></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#a').hmtl("<div>test</div>");
   });  
</script>
```

And the error is: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#a').hmtl("<div>test</div>")')`. Most of the answers I found here said to load JQuery before the script, which I am doing, to no avail.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$('#a').hmtl("<div>test</div>");
```

to

```
$('#a').html("<div>test</div>");
```

Comment: oh gosh…that is embarrassing. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have a spelling mistake: `$('#a').hmtl("<div>test</div>");`. It should be `html` not `hmtl`.

Comment: Oh dear…that is embarrassing. Thank you!

Comment: (Accepted srinath's answer just because that one was first…sorry)

Answer (score 0):

the function is undefined because it's not hmtl but html

thanks